# Inserting other fields in has_many through associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have 3 three models which is associated each others ..

Room Model

```
has_many :room_amenities
has_many :amenities, through: :room_amenities
```

Amenity Model

```
has_many :room_amenities
has_many :rooms, through: :room_amenities
```

RoomAmenity Model

```
belongs_to :amenity
belongs_to :room
```

I tried to insert my new room_amenity choice:

```
room = Room.find(28)
amenity = Amenity.where(id: [1,2])

rm_amenities = room.amenities = amenity
```

and it is successfully created but what if I want to insert other 2 fields like `Price` and `Hour` in room_amenities model

How could I insert that?

Comment: What do you mean by "insert"? Do you mean add them as attributes to the `room_amenities` table that didn't previously have those attributes? Sounds like you need such a table and just include `price` and `hour` as attributes. Or if price and hour only depend upon amenities, then add them as `amenities` table attributes.

Comment: Yes, I want to insert price and hour .. I already had a price and hour attributes in my room_amenities.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do

```
room = Room.find(28).room_amenities.new(amenity: Amenity.find(1), price: 100, hour: 2)
room.save
```

Comment: What if I have an array of object to insert? Should I do looping to make it like that?

Comment: I would say yes,you need to loop. In the above example you wrote `Amenity.where(id: [1,2])`, it ultimately would lead to invoking two sql inserts because Active Record wont perform batch insert.